# как в IDEA включить ResourceBundle mode

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, properties, resourcebundle

Пытаюсь редактировать закодированный файл типа `.properties` по этой [документации](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/editing-resource-bundle.html).

Нажимаю на *JUMP to Source*, но text-овый режим не включается. Может кто знает?!

Версия *IDEA 15* , *properties file* выглядит так:

```
lang.kaz.button.Kaz = \u049A\u0410\u0417
lang.ru.button.Kaz = \u0420\u0423\u0421
```

Comment: Что есть "закодированный файл"?

Comment: Кодировка файла properties должна быть UTF-8, а вы скорее всего набили текст в кодировке Win-1251 или что-то подобное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При нажатии `F4`на bundle Открывается специальный редактор где добавление нового свойства происходит по нажатию на зеленый плюс.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если открыть бандл и нажать на `F4` на конкретном файле, то тогда он откроется в текстовом редакторе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как быть с закодированными текстами типа \u049A\u0410\u0417 ?

Answer (score 3):

методом тыка нашел ответ переходим в настройки *IDEA* вкладке `FILE ENCODINGS`
 находим файл `.properties`и ставим птичку *transparent native-to-ascii conversion*

Answer (score 0):

Установите плагин редактора пакетов ресурсов Установите плагин редактора пакетов ресурсов, чтобы иметь возможность работать со свойствами: В диалоговом окне Настройки / предпочтения Ctrl+Alt +S выберите Плагины. Перейдите на вкладку Marketplace и введите Редактор пакетов ресурсов в строке поиска. Нажмите кнопку Установить рядом с именем плагина, примените изменения и закройте диалоговое окно.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/internationalization-and-localization.html#a.install-plugin